# Hazy patch with huge comet tail

Tags: star-gazing

Tonight between 4:30 am & 5 am, we were star gazing on a skyscraper. We saw hazy illuminated triangle patch. We took out star app but didn't find any comet passing through that region & I was sure it wasn't Andromeda Galaxy. I'm not sure what I watched.

Please note we thought it could be light of aeroplane, but we were sure it wasn't as it didn't move quickly. The second thought was some form of satellite. I think there isn't any satellite with that much light.

Please can anyone help me identify hazy triangle patch in the sky. I am attaching star map of my sky. The region I saw the hazy patch is marked with red circle on the map.

I'm based out of Mumbai. I don't want my curiosity to die without knowing what I saw, I'm happy to be wrong if it isn't any stellar object. Thank you.

[image: Sky Map from my area]

Comment: What were the weather and lighting conditions? Was this with the naked eye or were you using optics?

Comment: Weather for clear, lighting was intense and we saw it with our naked eyes, it could clouds as mentioned  in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see from the app, there are no hazy objects there, and in the light polluted Mumbai skies, deep sky objects would not be easily visible. There are no bright naked eye comets visible at the moment.

Satellites appear like moving stars, not hazy. The most likely hazy object would be a high cloud or part of a contrail, perhaps lit by the light of the city, or by the first light of dawn.

Comment: I'm convinced that it could be cloud. Let's say if it weren't clouds, who do we report such events?